# Unable to uninstall Skype for Business from Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016, skype-for-business

Every time I start-up my mother's PC I note that `Skype for Business` also starts up. I would like to uninstall this program and install the normal Skype. I have managed to install normal `Skype` fine but am struggling to uninstall `Skype for Business` as I cant find it registered as installed - please see the below screenshots to get an idea of my environment.

**1. Skype for Business included in PC start-up**

[image]

**2. Unable to see it in the list of Startup programs**

[image]

**3. Unable to see it in the Control Panel**

[image]

**4. Unable to see it in Apps and Features**

[image]

**5. No entry found in the Uninstall folder of the Registry**

[image]

**6. Unable to access individual programs of the Office Suite to modify/uninstall**
[image]

**7. Using Skype for Business 2016 on Windows 10**
[image]

**8. Tried configuring to not start-up during Windows Start but doesnt work**
[image]

I am really confused by what is going on here. Any hints/tips would be really appreciated. Perhaps its not possible to remove `Skype for Business` from this suite - but any tips how to at least stop it starting up when I log into Windows would be much appreciated.

**9. [UPDATE-1]** following the suggestion from @John below I installed `autoruns` discovered the entries for `Skype for Business` - unchecked them and rebooted my pc
[image]

but disappointingly the `Skype for Business` programme still starts on Windows start-up.

Comment: Try removing Skype for Business entries in Autoruns (SysInternals) and then restart and try again to install Skype personal.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @John - I tried out your idea please see the updated entry in the main question under 9. Sadly Skype for Business still starts. Am I missing something ?

Comment: There may have been something that compromised the system. Short of reinstalling Windows, I do not know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

check the properties of the shortcut and locate "Target" This is where the shortcut opens the actual app. My Skype for Business however was part of the Office 365 I have bought and I decided to just turn-off the automatic startup for it in the settings of Skype for Business itself. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, how is this related to uninstalling it? Could you be more specific?